# Trying to load large amount of JSON data in UITableView taking much time

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm new to iOS and have been trying to load JSON data in UITableView (within a UIViewController, which are in a Tab bar controller). The JSON data is huge and I have tried using `AFNetworking` library as well. But still the data takes more that 15 secs. to load.

Here is what I've tried:
Approach #2

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.


[self saveData];



return YES;
}
-(void) saveData
{
NSString * userType= @"3" ; 
NSString * userID= @"33" ;
NSString * URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://<some_url>/%@/%@/",userType,userID];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer =[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:leadsURLString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSData* responseObject) {
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray * lData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Leads:%@",lData);


    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    // Write the file .
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * lFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"leads"]]; // File

    if (![leadsData writeToFile:lFilePath atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save leads data.");
    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

}
@end
Code for tableView
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * projFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"leads"]]; // file
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:projFilePath])
{
    _projects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:projFilePath];

}
else
{
    _projects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"No Project" forKey:@"project_name"]];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

> 1. Initially tried loading data when the view controllers load, took too long.
> 2. Then tried loading data in Appdelegate and saving it, and loading it when the view controllers load, still took long enough.
> 3. Tried loading data in Appdelegate and then setting it in the respective view controllers, but couldn't achieve it.

Could anyone suggest the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: add tried code .

Comment: added tried code.

Comment: if it is taking much time to get data, it might be issue of internet speed or server. you can't do anything in that!  once you get response, you should reload your tableview, that's it!  your side is completed then!

Comment: I'm doing exactly that in my viewControllers, reloading tableView. And as you say, it might be an issue, as around 6000+ records are loading. But is this too much for JSON data?

Comment: add code for showing in tableview.

Comment: @SahebRoy, added the code for tableView. But I think #@Lion is right.

Comment: test what is the average time by using a rest client. That way we can be sure about the internet speed and the server . Preferably use Postman or ARC by chrome

Comment: used Postman, the response time is 3437 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if data is much larger(as you mentioned in comment) then you can manage your `api` something like you can send last index to server and server returns data from that index and you can define total number of records should be return in one call. then you can frequently call `api` as user scrolls your table view!

For example you could consider `facebook app's time line` or `Quora app's read` tab!

Comment: I may have to check with the other team on this one. Thanks for all the help, @Lion. appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow below steps to reduce the time.

Step: 1 Try to load data from below check how time it will take.

```
                 AFHTTPSessionManager *managerFB = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
                 [managerFB GET:WEB_SERIVCE_URL parameters:dicData progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
                     <#code#>
                 } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
                     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                     <#code#>
                 }];
```

Step: 2: Don’t try to save data into local file. Create one global variable in AppDelegate and stored directly into it.

Step: 3: Try to call service in background thread, so your main application UI won’t be stuck.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

Also, you can check your web-service response time in Postman which is extension of Chrome. So you can get response time from service.

Comment: Tried this approach as well, was a bit faster, but only by 2 secs. Thanks for your reply @Nirmalsinh .

Comment: Can you give me url and request data? So I can check at my end.

Comment: I would love to do that, but business clauses and restrictions prohibit me. Hope you understand. Thank you @Nirmalsinh I appreciate your help

Comment: One more thing you can check, if you are getting more amount of data, then try to divide into small small chunk. So it won't take more time to load. Also if you use tableview and your cell size is same, then don't write heightForCell method, directly give static height from storyboard.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm using custom cells , but I have set the height in storyboard.

Comment: What is the number of records do you in response??

Comment: Then it must take a time to render cell. Can give me you cell code?? So may be I can optimize it.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward
....- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary * project = [_projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString * proj_name = [project valueForKey:@"project_name"];
        cell.textLabel.text = proj_name;
    return cell;
}